# Is there a way to get Intellij to warn me that this code may cause a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, nullpointerexception

Is there a way to get Intellij to warn me that this may cause a NullPointerException?

```
URL resource = Main.class.getResource("blah/ha");
System.out.println(resource.getAuthority());  //potential NPE here
```

Intellij is great at warning me about stupid things I'm doing.  Is there a way it can warn me about the potential NPE here?

Please be aware that **`getResources` does not have any of those null/notnull annotations on it**.  At least not in JDK 1.7 which is what I'm using.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/howto.html

Comment: @Shashank I'll read that, but I don't think `getResource` uses annotations.

Comment: That's a good point...Here's another link I found: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/static_code_analysis.html This talks about IntelliJ's static code analysis features and it seems to have a section on managing static code analysis through custom inspection profiles...Hope this helps.

Comment: What about integrating with findbug or the likes? Would that helps?

Comment: Practically any code can cause an NPE.

Comment: IntelliJ allows you to create your own `annotations.xml` containing custom annotations: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/external-annotations.html

Answer (score 5):

Intellij idea can detect where @Nullable and @NotNull annotations are appropriate and [automatically insert them](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/12/auto-infer-nullablenotnull-annotations/). This can be done with

> Analyze -> Infer Nullity

This way you can automatically add these annotations to current file, uncommited files or various other scopes.

Disadvantage of this approach is that you have to have control over the code you are analyzing, so you cannot use it for third party code. Starting with Intellij Idea 14, there is a feature called [Automatic @NotNull/@Nullable/@Contract inference](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/10/automatic-notnullnullablecontract-inference-in-intellij-idea-14/). This feature is active in intellij idea 14 by default. Idea analyzes the source code and automatically detects whether there should be @Nullable or @NotNull annotation. The key difference from infer nullity is that it actually does not insert the anotation to the code itself, but only displays contract information on the left editor bar. This is especially good if you are working with third party libraries or do not want proprietary jetbrains annotations in your code.

[image: Auto-inferred @NotNull annotations]

**UPDATE:**

Note that @Nullable annotation is no longer automatically inferred asit resulted in too many false positives https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-130063#comment=27-812471

Also, according [a comment](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/10/automatic-notnullnullablecontract-inference-in-intellij-idea-14/#comment-269959) by Peter Gromov for this author of the [post mentioned above](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/10/automatic-notnullnullablecontract-inference-in-intellij-idea-14/), not all methods are inferred by this feature

> Please also note that contracts are not inferred for methods that can
>   be overridden, i.e. non-static non-private non-final methods don’t
>   have contracts.

Comment: That is some really useful information.  Thanks.  So why doesn't Intellij warn me on the second line of my example?

Comment: Do you have version 14? Do you have community or ultimate edition?

Comment: I updated my answer with possible reasons why this feature might not work in your case.

Answer (score 2):

### IntelliJ IDEA Inspections

One way is to use [Inspections](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/code-inspection.html?search=inspection).

Provided that the code is annotated by `@Nullable` annotations you can use inspections:

[image: Analyze menu]

And then choose `Run Inspection by Name`:

[image: @Nullable problems]

Then you can choose the scope (Project, Tests, etc.)

[image]

Results will be shown in inspection tab:

[image]

### Nullable How-To

You can find more on this in [Nullable How-To](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/howto.html)

Comment: "Provided that the code is annotated by @Nullable annotations..." It isn't.

Comment: True. Still this might help others, I can remove it if you think it's totally irrelevant btw :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on your current class >> analyze >> run inspection by name >> choose 'constant condition & exception'  'Java||Probable bugs'
2. Choose what you want to inspect and press ok.
3. In problems window, you will see suggestions offered by Intellij.

Comment: Hi, there's no 'constant condition & exception'. Also, an example of how that helps to find NPEs would be nice.